# Sitecore Social Connector (social media CMS Integration)

Tags: twitter, sitecore, twitter-oauth, sitecore8, sitecore-social-connected

I have created Social connector in Sitecore for twitter and i was able to login and redirect to some pages in my website. and it has created a new user profile in Sitecore under extranet domain. *(same question posted in sitecore forum as well https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/819*)

Is there any way to login to sitecore using those new users? and I want to access some of their basic information from social media such as full name email address DOB and etc.

Answer (score 0):

The users will need to use your login page (with twitter login) to login to the site.

User's basic information is stored in the user profiles, you may access it using:
Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomPropertyNames and
Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty

If you can't see some properties, they might be not enabled in Sitecore.Social.ProfileMapping.Twitter.config